# expressJS & AJAX: Update content of a view without rendering it

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, ejs

I have a app with several routes. If the route "/assessment" is called it renders an HTML page with a title and a button. Now if I click the button, the content of the page should be updated without re-loading it.

Currently, I solved it by using AJAX and creating a route for updating the content "/content-update".

This is the JS file for creating the intitial assessment page `assessment.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var createPage = require('../public/javascripts/createPage');
let ejs = require('ejs');

//Create x number of pages for the assessment
var pages = createPage(4);
console.log(pages);

/* GET assessment page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('assessment', {
    title: pages[0].title,
    pageNumber: pages[0].page,
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

It renders the view `assessment.ejs`

```
<%- include ("../views/header.ejs") -%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/index.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/updateContent.js"></script>
<body>
  <h1 id="title" pageNumber="<%= pageNumber %>"><%= title %></h1>
  <button
    onclick="updateContent(document.getElementById('title').getAttribute('pageNumber'))"
  >
    Update Content
  </button>
</body>

<%- include ("../views/footer.ejs") -%>
```

When clicking on the button the function `updateContent()` within in `updateContent.js` is called and I hand over the `pageNumber` attribute of the `h1` element that I want to update.

The function for fetching the `/update-content` endpoint looks like that:

```
function updateContent(pageNumber) {
  fetch('/update-content?pageNumber=' + pageNumber)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = data.title;
      document
        .getElementById('title')
        .setAttribute('pagenumber', data.pageNumber);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error));
}
```

The problem is that the `pageNumber` I hand-over to `updateContent` is a string but I need an integer to manipulate it and loop trough an array, that contains the content I want to use to update the page content:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var createPage = require('../public/javascripts/createPage');
let ejs = require('ejs');

//Create x number of pages for the assessment
var pages = createPage(4);
console.log(pages);

/* GET assessment page. */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let pageNumber = req.query.pageNumber; // Access pageNumber from query parameters
  res.json({
    title: pages[pageNumber + 1].title,
    pageNumber: pages[pageNumber + 1].page,
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

How would you approach this problem in general?
Is there a way that I can parse the `pageNumber` to an integer?